# angular-formly input label not showing

Tags: angular-formly

I have a frustrating issue with the `type` set as `input` I cant see the label.
 Its works fine if I use `type` as `select`. This is my code:

```
{
            "type": "input",
            "key": "firstName",
            "templateOptions": {
                "type": "text", 
                "placeholder": "jane doe",
                "label": "First name"
            }
        },
```

that doesn't show the label but this does:

```
{
"key": "transportation",
"type": "select",
"templateOptions": {
    "label": "How do you get around in the city",
    "valueProp": "name",
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "Car"
        },
        {
            "name": "Helicopter"
        }                
    ]
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated ?

Comment: Hmmm... Not sure what the problem is. Could you follow the instructions here: http://help.angular-formly.com

Comment: You might want to share a failing jsbin example

Comment: yes.. could you share the failing jsbin.. so that we can get what's the issue and share some ideas